# Why does path-completion in bash not always work?

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete

With different bash-environments (different installations) I have different behaviors in terms of path-completion when hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> on the command line after . Where is this handled?

One specific example:

I run `cmake` with a `-D`-argument:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/x-too<TAB>
```

it does nothing. Whereas (notice the space between `=` and `~`

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE= ~/x-too<TAB>
```

completes to

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE= ~/x-tools
```

On other systems it even works with no space between = and ~.

Where do I find the related configuration-files and values?

Answer (score 4):

Linux autocompletions work with `complete`.

```
 ]➬complete -p  cmake
 complete -F _cmake cmake
```

So _cmake is in charge.

```
]➬type _cmake > cmake.sh
```

And now just see/debug it. You modify in for example _cmake_mine and call to test it:

```
. cmake.sh
complete -F _cmake_mine cmake
```

To get help for **any builtin** bash command:

```
 help complete
 help [[
 help for
```

Comment: never knew `help` was the `man` for bash builtins!

Answer (score 3):

You have to start with `/etc/profile`. See what other files are sourced by that (with the `.` command probably).

For example on my Ubuntu system,

- `/etc/profile` sources all *.sh file in `/etc/profile.d/`
- `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` sources `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`
- that file:

  - sets up a completion loader function that looks in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`
  - and sources `~/.bash_completion`

You'll want to follow that path on your various systems. Perhaps there's no `cmake` file in /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ on one of them.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts. For some reason this is not always set up in Ubuntu 16.04.